# Replacing word from string by giving start and end point only replaces first match

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

This is my code

```
var str = 'test test';              
var start = 5;               
var end = 9;                
var val = 'success';                 
var ta1 = $("#textbox").val();        
$("#textbox").val(ta1.replace(ta1.substr(start,end),val));
```

Its output is = `success test`

But I want to give start and end points to replace the second test word in string. how can I do it ?

Perhaps there is some alternative to replace?

Comment: Do you mean you want to use mutliple replace? Use `RegExp` with `g` modifier. `$("#textbox").val(ta1.replace(RegExp(ta1.substr(start,end), "g"),val));` Do you need to replace all of the `test`s? See http://jsfiddle.net/xmfs4t0d/1/

Comment: is it like var str = 'test test';
str.replace(/(test)/g,'sucess')

Comment: i want to change second test in string by giving start and end points

Comment: @MJunaidAslam: Please check my answer. I found a way to replace only the necessary match and keep others intact.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the offset within a callback function:

```js
var start = 9;               
var end = 16;                
var val = 'success';                 
var ta1 = $("#textbox").val();
rx = RegExp(ta1.substr(start,end - start), "g"); // RegExp is formed with global flag to test all matches
console.log(rx);
$("#textbox").val(ta1.replace(rx, function(m, offset, input) {
    var result = offset === start ? val : m;  // Here, we check if the offset is our start position
    return result;
 }));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="textbox" rows="20">this
is 
testing
test</textarea>
```

So, basically, you need to:

- Get your replacement string with a `substr` function
- Create a global RegExp object using a constructor
- Inside a replace, define the callback function to check the starting offset, and if the offset is equal to the *start* variable value, perform the replacement.

Comment: it do not work if i select a text in range it copies that text and other some text at the end of string. do not replace the exact text.

Comment: it do not work on textarea with multiple line. please add break k line in this textarea.                                     <textarea id="textbox"  >test 
    test</textarea>

Comment: And where is the line break? What do `start` and `end` look like? Please provide a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/. Or add it to the question itself.

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/junaid720/q8p6k6ns/) there is exact code and i want to replace testing in that string thanks.

Comment: Here is an [updated code](http://jsfiddle.net/2qvezn5e/). See the console: 1) the substring to replace looks like `s\ntesting\nte`, 2) the problem you had with the snippet was the final unpaired `}`, 3) the result I get is `this\nisuccessst` - not sure it is expected, but the code is working 100%. BTW, you can see the pattern of the compiled regex with `console.log(rx.source);`.

Comment: if i replace testing in this string then next code automatically skipped. please see this problem.

Comment: The problem was with `String#substr` function: its second argument is *length*, not the *end* parameter. See updated answer.